# What does this person say in this video?

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, slang, conversation

I don't know if this is allowed but I want to know what this Gwyneth Paltrow say in this video at 0:51 to be exact.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZORey6EHF3g
or

http://www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/article-1380647/Gwyneth-Paltrow-shatters-clean-cut-image-dropping-C-bomb-U-S-chat-Chelsea-Lately.html

*scroll down to see the video

Does she say "I really sight or cite?"

I have a feeling that it basically means that she's so happy but I do want to know how to spell the word.

Again, I am heaps sorry if this isn't allowed but I do no know where to ask.

Thanks heaps!

Comment: "The uploader has not made this video available in your country. "

Comment: NOOOOOOOOOOO :( this is what Im concern about.. Wait :(

Comment: http://www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/article-1380647/Gwyneth-Paltrow-shatters-clean-cut-image-dropping-C-bomb-U-S-chat-Chelsea-Lately.html

I hope you can play that one.. scroll down to watch the video. @code19

Comment: Not available to me either but there's a good chance it's _psyched_. See definition 1b here http://www.thefreedictionary.com/psyched

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is likely

> I'm really psyched

*Excited, pumped up*

Comment: Ahh!!! I see! I knew this word before, but I don't know why I didn't think about 'psyched' for this sentence bofore... thanks a lot!

Comment: It is not the original meaning but is used a lot - especially about projects